# Получить список устройств в локальной сети Windows Universal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Добрый день. Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить список всех устройств в сети в приложении UWP. Например: у меня в одной сети находится 2 компьютер а и 2 телефона, роутер им выдаёт ip-адрес. На выходе я хочу получить список, в котором все эти 4 устройства, каждое из которых имеет DisplayName, Ip и любые другие данные вроде Mac-адреса. То, что предлагает майкрософт никак не получается использовать. Там либо пара устройств, либо больше тысячи и ни в одном и ни во втором случае там правды нет.